How to prove that this equation has no other integer solutions?
To find the integer solutions of an indeterminate equation and prove that there are no other solutions, where all variables are positive integers and n can be regarded as a constant, let's first analyze the given situation where by observation we found that k=1,n1=n2=n is a solution to the equation. However, the question remains: Is this the only possible solution?
$$k2^{2n}-(2k-1)2^n+k-1=k2^{n_1+n_2}-2^{n_2}$$

The only solution in positive integers to equation
$$2^{2n} k−(2k−1)2^n+k−1=2^{a+b} k−2^{a}$$
is $k=1$, $a=b=n$. To prove this claim, we use the elementary inequality $2^b -1\ge 2^{b-1}$ and remark that in any solution in positive integers one necessarily has $k$ odd.
Assume there is a solution with $k\ge 3$. The left-hand side is less than $2^{2n} k$, while the right-hand side is greater than $2^a (2^b-1)k \ge 2^{a+b-1}k$. Hence,
$$2n \ge a+b.$$
To get a lower bound for $a+b$, rewrite the equation as
$2^n+2^{a}−1=\bigl(2^{a+b} -(2^n-1)^2  \bigr)k$. The LHS being positive, so is the RHS. Therefore,
$$ a+b> 2n-2.$$
There are two cases to examine.
Case $a+b=2n$. The equation becomes  $2^n+2^a-1=(2^{n+1}-1)k$.  The RHS is $\ge 3(2^{n+1}-1) > 2^{n+2}$,  so we conclude that it holds $a\ge n+2$. This in turn implies $k=2^n c+1 $ for some odd positive integer $c$. Writing the equation in terms of $c$, one gets  $2^{a-n}-1= (2^{n+1}-1) c$. Here, the LHS is less than $2^{n-1}$ (remember $2n=a+b\ge a+1$), while the RHS is at least $2^{n+1}-1 >2^n$.
Case $a+b=2n-1$. Note that from $a$, $b\ge 1$ it follows that $n\ge 2$. The equation is now  $\bigl( 2^{2n-1}k-(2k-1)2^n\bigr) +(k-1) +2^a=0$. As both differences within parantheses are positive for  $n$, $k>1$, this equality is false.

Very good, thank you very much. But how to get it
a+b>2n−2
Please provide more details.

@LiSong   $2^{a+b} > (2^n -1)^2\ge 2^{2(n-1)}$

how to get it  $k=2^nc+1$,Please provide more details

@LiSong Rewrite $2^n+2^a-1=(2^{n+1}-1)k$ as $k=2^n(2k-1-2^{a-n})+1$ and remember $a\ge n+2$.
